# Delete duplicate blank attribute in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

**Environment**
OpenLDAP v2.4 with OLC (On-Line Configuration / cn=config) in a mirror mode cluster on Ubuntu 16.04. The database was migrated from another server via LDIF and slapadd. Some groups were empty so I bulk added a blank `uniqueMember` attribute to all groups.

**Problem**
Some groups have 2 `uniqueMember` attributes with no value. Some groups have this blank member as their only member just to keep the group in existence, so I can not indiscriminately remove it from all groups.

**Question(s)**
1. How can I remove the blank `uniqueMember` attribute? (Preferably only from groups where it is duplicated.)
2. Is there a better way to satisfy the requirement of having a member in a group when there are no actual members that belong to the group?

I will gladly write a script to process the entire directory if need be, but I'm stuck on how to actually match and delete the blank entry and how to find the group entries with duplicates with an ldap search.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14457703/7680208), there is no way to filter a blank value in LDAP. I was able to manually find all groups with duplicate blanks and the best solution I find to fix them is to export the group to LDIF, modify the LDIF file and re-add the group.